# Download startup config from Cisco device using SCP

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I can successfully programmatically download the config from Juniper network devices using SCP - I'd like to do the same for a Cisco router.

SSH access is already working, and I've enabled SCP using `ip scp server enable`. Problem is that I don't know the name or location of the file I need to download, and GUI tools like WinSCP don't seem to work (complains that I need a BASH shell).

Is this possible for Cisco devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out - I was quoting the filename, which seems to work just fine for other devices, such as Juniper devices, but not for Cisco IOS.

I was doing this:

`scp -f "system:running-config"`

But this is what works:

`scp -f system:running-config`

Answer (score 4):

`scp <user>@<router>:startup-config` (or `running-config`)

Or the full pathname of whatever file you want, like *nvram:/startup-config*.

[there's also the `CONFIG-COPY-MIB` to initiate a copy by SNMP. It's come up many times before, so go [here](http://checkforbees.com/router-backup/)]

Comment: Your scp command does work with the scp executable, but I'm trying to do this programmatically. I can open an scp connection and send commands, such as `scp -f my_filename`, but the Cisco SCP server always says it can't find the file when I try anything like `system:running-config`. Not sure if some alternative syntax is required or what. The SNMP stuff is also helpful, I'll look into that too

Comment: That's an issue with your SSH client. Perhaps it's trying *sftp* instead of scp?

Comment: I'm using Cisco IOS 12.4, which I don't think supports SFTP?